# What is 'Page scope' in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

There are following scopes in **JSP**:

- **page scope**
- **request scope**
- **session scope**
- **application scope**

I am confused about page scope. Can anybody tell me what is this **page scope**? I have not found its clear definition anywhere.

Comment: What did you find about page scope and what don't you understand about it?

Answer (score 13):

`page` scope means, it can be thought of as an object that represents the entire JSP page,i.e. the JSP object can be accessed only from within the same page where it was created.
The page object is really a direct synonym for the `this` object.
**Note**:

> The main difference between **page** scope and **request** scope(often confusing ) is that page scope attributes are no longer available if the request is forwarded to another JSP page where as request scope attributes are available.

Comment: Suppose there is page which includes another page.So the translation unit consists of both including and included page.Then according to my understanding object in page scope is available to all pages that are involved in the translation unit. Am i wrong?

Comment: Hi. I will thanks you, if could tell me if one variable within scriptlet (<% %>) could be named like page scope?. I have read that variables within scriptles are local variables, then I think that it could be named page variables (o what can be the difference). Regards.

Answer (score 9):

The **page scope** indicates that, in addition to
being bound to a local variable, the bean object should be placed in
the [**`javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html) object for the duration of the current request.

Acording to Allamaraju (2004):

> JSP defines four scopes for the objects that can be used by the JSP authors:
>
> - **page** - Objects can be accessed only within the JSP page in which they are referenced.
> - **request** - Objects can be accessed within all the pages that  serve the current request. These include pages that are forwarded to, and included in, the original JSP page to which the request was routed.
> - **session** - Objects can only be accessed within the JSP pages accessed within the session for which the objects are defined.
> - **application** - Application scope objects can be accessed by all  JSP pages in a given context.

Storing the object there means that servlet code can access it by
calling `getAttribute()` on the predefined `pageContext` variable. Since every page and every request has a different `PageContext` object, this indicates that the bean is not shared and thus a new bean will be created for each request.

---

**References**

Allamaraju, S. (2004). *Professional Java Servlets 2.3.* Berkeley, Calif: Apress.