# Difference between page scope and request scope in Servlet & JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, scope

I have gone through below links so far-:
[Page scope- scope in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22766332/page-scope-scope-in-jsp)
[What are the different scopes in JSP?](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1009)
[difference between page and request](https://coderanch.com/t/291025/java/difference-page-request)

I want to know about what are the differences between **page scope** and **request scope**? If I consider use of **RequestDispatcher.forward()** & **HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()** to same or different page, then how these scopes will work?
 If request is **forwarded** to **same page** then how these two scopes will differ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page scope is a scope that in valid only while processing one single JSP. Typically, if one JSP forwards to itself, the second instanciation will share the original request scope but will receive a brand new page scope. This can make sense if you include 2 instances of the same fragment in on page: all will share the request scope with the caller, but each instance will use its own page scope.

`sendRedirect` is quite a different thing! Redirecting is returning to the client a special response containing the new URL to fetch in its headers. But that also means that the redirect will use a different HTTP request and as such will have a different request scope. Said differently only session scope is shared between redirected pages - and only when you redirect to the same web application.

Answer (score 3):

Notice more than one page can serve a single request. see [article](http://javapapers.com/jsp/explain-the-scope-of-jsp-objects/).

You also can see in [example](http://www.dineshonjava.com/2013/09/jsp-scopes-example.html) that you can forward a parameter with request scope to another page by forward.

> **page**
>
> ‘page’ scope means, the JSP object can be accessed only from
>   within the same page where it was created. The default scope for JSP
>   objects created using  tag is page. JSP implicit objects
>   out, exception, response, pageContext, config and page have ‘page’
>   scope.
>
> **request**
>
> A JSP object created using the ‘request’ scope can be
>   accessed from any pages that serves that request. More than one page
>   can serve a single request. The JSP object will be bound to the
>   request object. Implicit object request has the ‘request’ scope.